# Replacing only the characters in a string that exist between 2 others PHP

Tags: php, regex, string

I have an array of data in PHP about people where each line contains a string of details about that individual.

```
[0] => name1,email1,year1,"country1a,country1b",date1
[1] => name2,email2,year2,"country2a,country2b,country2c",date2
.... etc
```

The problem I am having is that I need to explode each line by commas into a multi-d array for the way I am going to process it, and that "country,country" section is messing things up because they need to be exploded as 1 item. The formatting is identical between each line, but the number of countries can vary.

I am trying to replace only those commas between the "" with another delimiter | so that I can explode them by that later.

I've tried several different strnpos and str_replace and from my searching I think preg_replace is going to be the best option but I'm having a really hard time with the regex syntax. strnpos and str_replace don't seem very efficient with having to keep track of so many different string positions at once--this is the way I tried originally with finding the positions of the ""s. It seems like this should be a simple thing to do but it hasn't been turning out that way. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer today on the 4th day of searching! It had never come up in my results before.

https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110425205225AAVdOh1 This answer worked perfectly when implemented as such:

```
foreach($tblArray as &$str) {
  $pattern = '/".+"/i';
  preg_match($pattern,$str,$matches);
  $orig = $matches[0];
  $edited = str_replace(', ','|',$orig);
  //also removed the ""s for future processing's sake
  $edited = str_replace('"',"",$edited);
  $str = str_replace($orig,$edited,$str);
}
```

It's pretty simple although I hadn't been thinking about a more 2-step process like this previously. I end up with

```
[0] => name1,email1,year1,country1a|country1b,date1
[1] => name2,email2,year2,country2a|country2b|country2c,date2
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a bit of an XY problem. You want to split the items in a line, but to do that you're trying to replace the commas in quotes so that they don't interfere with the commas that separate values.

Take a step back, and try:

```
preg_match_all('/("[^"]+"|[^,]+),?/',$line,$matches);
$result = $matches[1];
```

This should give you an array containing the items, which will either be comma-separated or delimited by quotes. The `,?` at the end just makes sure that the commas are consumed and not matched.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach($array as &$value)if(strpos($value,',')!==false)$value=explode(',',$value);
```

I made this out of memory, it might not work.

Comment: How is that? You have an array with a string with a delimiter (the coma ',' in this example) and it splits it into array elements.

Comment: Okay... but OP wants to handle quoted parts of the string appropriately. Your code disregards them entirely.

Comment: Aren't the quoted parts simply strings in the array?

Answer (score 0):

```
(?=(?:[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"))*[^"]*$),
```

this will do what you want.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lB2sH2/3